# CSS Transform rotation on button click

Tags: html, css

I have a simple Login form and Registration form, currently they rotate at the y-axis when the container is hovered on, and then rotate back to start when the hover is removed.

what I need is to bind it so when the Register Button is clicked, it flips to the backside (registration page) and then if I click the To Login Button, it reverts back to the front side again.

here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fr5ND/) to eliminate a wall of text.

any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple, you were almost there. Since you have

```
/*#f1_container:hover #f1_card,*/ #f1_container.hover_effect #f1_card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

in your CSS, you just need to add/ remove the `.hover_effect` class when clicking the Register/ To Login buttons, that's all.

It only takes a bit of JavaScript:

```
var face_changers = document.querySelectorAll('.btnFlip'), 
    f1_container = document.getElementById('f1_container');

for(var i = 0; i < face_changers.length; i++){
    face_changers[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        f1_container.classList.toggle('hover_effect');
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
}​
```

## [*demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/Fr5ND/3/)

[note that I also commented out the hover part so there is no flip on hover anymore; apart from that, I haven't made any changes to the CSS or the HTML]

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add a class to the beginning of the following selector

```
#f1_container:hover #f1_card, #f1_container.hover_effect #f1_card
```

that sets the rotate to zero, then toggle that class on click.

Edit:

You are using the selector to rotate the card

```
#f1_container:hover #f1_card, #f1_container.hover_effect #f1_card {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

in order to not always have it rotate when you hover, you will need to provide an even more specific selector to override that rule. You can do this by adding any selector before it. The best way to do this is normally adding a class to the parent element. So the new rule will look like this

```
.registered#f1_container:hover #f1_card, .registered#f1_container.hover_effect #f1_card {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0);
  -o-transform: rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateY(0);
}
```

that will match an element with the id of f1_container **as well as** a class of registered, as opposed to just an element with the id of f1_container

You will want to toggle this class on the element by executing a bit of javascript when you click on the register button.

You don't have a unique id or class on the button, so the jQuery selector for the click listener is a bit hairy

```
$('#frmReg button:not(".btnFlip")').on('click', function(){
  $('btnFlip').addClass('registered')
})
```

Obviously if you were to just add an id to that button itd be a bit simpler.

Comment: You might want to be a bit more specific.

Comment: unless that is a pun on css specificity (in which case, bravo), could you let me know what is unclear?

Comment: For other users, you may want to outline what to do specifically.  Right now it's rather general and difficult to figure out for users that are not well versed in css3.